# Can we enforce max usage limits or max cost ($) for Member accounts in an AWS Organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-billing

We are using AWS Organisations service (with Consolidated Billing feature) with a large member of accounts. Can we set a max limit somehow for the usage cost ($) of the Member accounts?

Comment: You can create a billing alert, then hook an activity on the alert (like stopping services,...)

Comment: Would you add a little more detailed description about how can I hook an activity on a billing alert?

Answer (score 1):

> Would you add a little more detailed description about how can I hook an activity on a billing alert?

I am not sure about your exact requirements, you may check the documentation:

- [Monitor Your AWS Charges with Billing Alerts](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/10/announcing-aws-billing-alerts/).
- [Managing Your Costs with Budgets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-managing-costs.html)

In both cases you can setup alerts on cost/budget, where an alert event is sent to an SNS topic. SNS topic can further send a mail, but the same way you can implement any functionality listening on the topic (e.g. a lambda function)

This way you may monitor total cost/budget usage

> usage cost ($) of the Member accounts

You can have a look at [Cost Explorer](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-reports/hom) where you can create cost reports per tag or as well per account

(I am not sure if you can create an alert for cost per account)

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box enforcement to limit the usage of your AWS account. Alerts can only notify you that you're not in your forecasted budget, but that's it mostly, the rest you should implement on your own.

Couple of thoughts:

1. **Enforcing** max limit on your production account is not best practice. You don't want a production interruption or user impact because of a needed scale up in infra.
2. What you can do is to map your needs and usage, and set quota limits to services. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html - again, this is not really recommended. Just make sure you have visibility on your growth, set alerts and monitor your usage. Optimization is a key in the could, and the financial responsibility is yours, not AWS.